# Excel - reordering table

Tags: excel, histogram

I have the following table:

```
Product Month   Price
AE1938242   Nov-16  427
AE1938243   Dec-16  465
AE1938244   Jan-17  388
AO9349394   Nov-16  272
AO9349395   Dec-16  326
AO9349396   Jan-17  263
R3234452    Nov-16  742
R3234453    Dec-16  906
R3234454    Jan-17  734
```

And I'm trying to get a histogram of the prices by month which looks like this:

[image: What I'm trying to get to]

The only way I was able to get this was by manually reordering the tables as such:

```
        AE1938242   AO9349394   R3234452
Nov-16  427 272 742
Dec-16  465 326 906
Jan-17  388 263 734
```

The original table has several rows - is there a better/more efficient way of grouping the data to get the monthly histogram? 
I'm using Excel on Mac if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the data you have and **enter it into a pivot table**, then use a pivot diagram to display the data.

I reproduced your diagram by using the original data set and putting the dates in the `Axis Field`, the Item Labels (SKEWs?) in the `Legends Field` and the Count in the `Data Field`.

Not sure if this is the answer you are looking for, but to do it non programmatically, to me this would be the easiest way.